# "order by" kills performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not a **MySQL** guy, actually I'm doing this to help a friend.
I have these tables in a **MySQL** database:

```
create table post (ID bigint, p text)

create table user (ID bigint, user_id bigint)
```

and I'm querying them by this script:

```
select * from post 
    where ID in (select user_id from user where ID = 50) 
    order by ID DESC --this line kills performance.
    limit 0,20
```

As I mentioned in comment, when there is no `order by ID DESC`, the query executes very fast. But when I add that to the query, it got very very slow with a huge CPU usage. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably nothing wrong, just that ordering is a costly operator. Do you have an index in the `ID` column?, how many rows are there in the table?

Comment: LIMIT costs, too, I believe.

Comment: What's the explain plan for this query?

Comment: Can you put EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of your query and paste the results? Also, please show the profile for this query (this link will explain how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html)

Comment: There are 50000 records.

Comment: Is that 50,000 records in the posts table or 50,000 records that match the `where` condition?

Comment: No they are in `post` table. There is a few records in `user` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define ID as Primary Key for your table. This will add an index and increase performance. At least as a first step, it's a good one.

This query should do the trick:

```
create table post (
  ID bigint, 
  p text,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Comment: Whould you tell me how to create index or define a column as PK. I'm a `T-SQL` guy and this is just a one-time use of `MySQL`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @frlan the problem got solved by indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_POST_ID ON post (ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER_ID ON user (ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER_USERID ON user (user_id);
```